# Prove that solutions of a linear system is a subsapce of $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

I have to prove that a group of solution of a linear system is a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^4$. How can I prove it?
The given system is:
\begin{align}
2x+y+t+z=0\\
x+3t+z=0\\
x+y-2t+z=0
\end{align}

Comment: Well, what is the definition of a subspace?  That is, what properties must a subset satisfy in order to be a subspace?

Comment: @lulu It must respect 3 rules; It must include O, closed for addition and multiplication. I don't know how to verify this after I solved the system

Comment: Which can't you verify?  Is $\vec 0=(0,0,0,0)$ a solution?  If $(x_1,y_1,z_1,t_1$ and $(x_2,y_2,z_2,t_2)$ are both solutions, is there sum a solution?  What about $(cx_1,cy_1,cz_1,ct_1)$?

Comment: @lulu so is it useless to solve the system? I can directly prove that this is a subspace

Comment: Oh, if you want to solve it directly that certainly gets the job done.  But it's more than you need.  If you had a billion equations of your form (in more than a billion variables), it would still be true that their solution formed a subspace...but solving it would be impractical.

Comment: I should stress that more. It is really obvious that $\vec 0$ is a solution.  It's obvious that any scalar multiple of a solution is a solution.  It's fairly clear that the sum of two solutions is a solution.  You can do all of that without ever solving.  Of course it's important that all your equations evaluate to $0$.

Comment: @lulu The problem has been solved, put your comment as an answer and I'll tick it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be the set of solutions.  To show that $V$ is a subspace we must show that it is closed under addition and scalar multiplication (we remark that $\vec 0\in V$ so we know that $V$ is not empty).

Scalar multiplication:  It is easily seen that if $\vec v=(x,y,z,t)\ in V $ is a solution then $c\vec v =(cx,cy,cz,ct)$ for $c\in \mathbb R$ is also a solution (indeed, the left hand of each equation is simply multiplied by $c$).

Addition:  if $\vec v=(x,y,z,t), \vec w = (X,Y,Z,T) \in V $ then, for example, we have $$2x+y+t +2z = 0 = 2X+Y+T+2Z\implies 2(x+X)+(y+Y)+(t+T)+2(z+Z)=0$$ and similarly for the other equations.  Thus $\vec v + \vec w\in V$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions of this equation are the.elements of the kernel of the marix given by the coeffiecients. The kernel of a 4*4 matrix is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^4}$